# Access 2013 auto removal of specific records in a query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm somewhat new to the coding side of access. In my database I have a linked table containing vehicle info. The first field in this table contains Vehicle VINs so the text is around 12-15 characters. What I'm trying to do is have a query of this field that will remove the entire row with less than 12 characters in that first column. I can do this for the specific text but is there a way to remove them no matter what the text is as long as its below that 12 character rule?

Answer (score 0):

SQL-Code:

```sql
DELETE * FROM TableVehicleInfo WHERE Len(VehicleVIN) < 12;
```

Store this as a query (e.g. qryDelVehicleInfoVinLess12).

It can be executed by double click or vba:

```vb
With CurrentDb()
    .Execute "qryDelVehicleInfoVinLess12", dbFailOnError
End With
```